# Is it possible to create all missing directory at once with make?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

The common pattern is:

```
obj/%.o : src/%.c
    mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    $(CC) -c $< -o $@
```

I am wondering if I can space the call to `mkdir` for each file. I came across this solution:

```
CSRC=some/path/here/foo.c another/directory/random/here/bar.c 
OBJDIR=obj/

objdirs = $(sort $(foreach path,$(CSRC),$(addprefix $(OBJDIR),$(dir $(path)))))
$(objdirs): %:
    mkdir -p $@ 

obj/%.o : src/%.c | $(objdirs)
    $(CC) -c $< -o $@
```

Is there a better solution?

Comment: In your solution, why do you have two recipes with `mkdir`? And why do you have different `objdirs` while they are apparently all the same: `obj/`? Note: you should avoid using `dir` as a make variable name because it is also a function name...

Comment: It was a mistake

Comment: Your solution still puzzles me. Is `$(OBJDIR)` equal to `obj/`? And what is `$(CSRC)`? Are you sure of your `objdirs` computation?

Comment: I have added definitions for OBJDIR and CSRC

Comment: So, what you want is, for each `some/path/here/foo.c` 1) create `obj/some/path/here/` if it does not exist yet and 2) compile `some/path/here/foo.c` as `obj/some/path/here/foo.o`?

Comment: @RenaudPacalet Yes exactly

Comment: How big is your project?  If you have ten files, then the `mkdir` inside of each target is fine, but, if you are building 30000 files, then 30000 `mkdir`s will add a minute to your build time.  At that point @Renaud's first solution  is better (his second solution is indeed not a good idea for the reasons he mentions).

Comment: Unfortunately the lost time it is much worse on Windows/Cygwin. I don't have 30k files but only few hundred.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple solution, but not 100% satisfactory, resembles yours:

```
OBJDIR      := obj
CSRC        := some/path/here/foo.c another/directory/random/here/bar.c
CSRCDIRS    := $(sort $(dir $(CSRC)))
objdirs     := $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/,$(CSRCDIRS))
OBJS        := $(patsubst %.c,$(OBJDIR)/%.o,$(CSRC))

$(OBJS): $(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.c | $(objdirs)
    $(CC) -c $< -o $@

$(objdirs):
    mkdir -p $@
```

It should work but its drawback is that **each** object file has **all** object directories as order-only prerequisite, which is overkill. All object directories will be created, even if only one object file is built. They will be created only once because they are order-only, but still, it is not 100% satisfactory.

In order to have only one order-only object directory prerequisite per object file, the only solution I see (but there may be better ones) is something like:

```
OBJDIR      := obj
CSRC        := some/path/here/foo.c another/directory/random/here/bar.c
CSRCDIRS    := $(sort $(dir $(CSRC)))
objdirs     := $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/,$(CSRCDIRS))

# $(1): source directory
define MY_rule
$(OBJDIR)/$(1)%.o: $(1)%.c | $(OBJDIR)/$(1)
    $(CC) -c $$< -o $$@
endef
$(foreach c,$(CSRCDIRS),$(eval $(call MY_rule,$(c))))

$(objdirs):
    mkdir -p $@
```

The iterator explicitly declares **each** object directory as the **only** order-only prerequisite of all object files **it** contains. But it is more difficult to understand (especially the `$$`). Is it worth the extra complexity?